# What's the best practice to fetch specific fields from big data coming from RESTful service in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, datamapper

I am calling RESTful service which return data contains a lot of fields, but I want to make interface like DTO to carry only data I need it.
I used pipe & map from rxjs but I dont know is this tha best practice or not:

**The returned data in usual:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {...}
]
```

**The data I only need it:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz"
  },
  {...}
]
```

**user Interface:**

```
export interface User {
    id?:number,
    name?:string,
    email?:string,
    username?:string
}
```

**user Service:**

```
export class UsersService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .pipe(
        map((data: User[]) =>
          data.map((item: User) => {
            return {
              id: item.id,
              name: item.name,
              email: item.email,
              username: item.username,
            };
          })
        )
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: seems fine to me - same approach I would have taken

Comment: looks quite good. But don't make all the properties optional in the interface if those are the properties you want. Also this means that `this.http.get` does not return `User[]`, neither is `map((data: User[])` true and also not `data.map((item: User)` true. only what you actually have after `return` **is** data of type `User`, i.e `return <User>{
              id: item.id,
              name: item.name,
              email: item.email,
              username: item.username,
            }`

Comment: @AJT82 when I make `this.http.get` does not return `User[]` I got this problem: **Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'**

Comment: Yes, that is because httpclient parses your response to an **anonymous object**, you **could** bypass this by declaring `any`, but that completely defeats the purpose of **Type**Script, so the correct way would do to make an interface for example called `UserResponse`, which describes the response you are initially getting... something like: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhxlf9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @AJT82 Thank you for your replay and nice example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

**user Interfaces:**

```
interface User {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  email: string,
  username: string
}

interface UserResponse {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: any; // lazily using 'any' here
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: any; // lazily using 'any' here
}
```

**user Service:**

```
export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<UserResponse[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .pipe(
        map((data: UserResponse[]) =>
          data.map((item: UserResponse) => {
            return <User>{
              id: item.id,
              name: item.name,
              email: item.email,
              username: item.username,
            };
          })
        )
      );
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhxlf9)